# Does every language in BPP have a mapping reduction to ATM?

Tags: complexity-theory, probabilistic-algorithms

Does every language $C$ in the class $BPP$ have a mapping reduction to $A_{TM}$?
$(C\leq _{m} A_{TM})$

$BPP$ is the class of languages that have a probabilistic $TM$ that accepts them with an error $\epsilon$ less than 1/3.

$A_{TM}$ is the acceptance language, takes as input a $TM$ description of $M$ and a word w, then determines if w is in $M$'s langugae. $A_{TM}$ is of course undecidable!

Comment: Note BPP is a subset of EXP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Every decidable language reduces to $A_{\mathrm{TM}}$.

Every language in **BPP** is decidable because the definition requires that every execution of the probabilistic machine halts in polynomial time. So you can just simulate out all the possibilities and compute the probability that the machine accepts.

Comment: If you can only clarify on why is it so, that every decidable language reduces to ATM? Is it because decidable languages have smaller time complexity than ATM? Thank you.

Comment: A $L$ language is decidable if ______. A string $x$ is in $L$ if ______. Now relate that to the definition of $A_{\mathrm{TM}}$.